# ¿Que hacer para que el texto y los elementos no se desborden en html5, css3 y bootstrap?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Estoy realizando un pequeño sistema en `HTML5`, `CSS3`,`JS`,`PHP` y `BOOTSTRAP`, el cual quiero que el texto se escale al tamaño de la pantalla.

Entiendo que `BOOTSTRAP` hace que el sitio se haga `responsive`, pero a la hora de escalar se me desbordan los títulos.

**Imagen del problema**

[image: Problema]

Quisiera saber ¿Qué tengo que hacer para que el texto o los elementos no se me desborden_

```css
html,body{
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.bgLogin{
 background-color: #E4E2E2;
}
.fullWidth{
 height: 100%;
}
#formLogin{
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
}
.textVerde{
 color: #006847;
}
.textRojo{
 color: #CE1126;
}
.header{
 background-color: #F1F0EB;
 height: 15%;
}
.footer{
 background-color: #776D5A; 
 height: 10%;
 position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   
}
.tablero{
 height: 70%;
}
.asideTablero{
 background-color: #AAFAC8;
}
.maxWidthHeigth{
 min-width: 10%;
 min-height: 10%;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height:100%; 
}
header h1{
 font-size:1.5em;
}
header h4{
 font-size:1.2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ES-MX">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Tablero Administrador</title>
  <!--CSS Bootstrap-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!--CSS FontAwesome-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-v2Tw72dyUXeU3y4aM2Y0tBJQkGfplr39mxZqlTBDUZAb9BGoC40+rdFCG0m10lXk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/fontawesome.css">
  <!--CSS Local-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../CSS/sce2018.css">
  <!--Script Jquery-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
 <header class="card-header container-fluid header maxWidthHeigth"">
  <div class="row justify-content-center maxWidthHeigth">
   <h1 class="maxWidthHeigth">Bienvenido(a) <small class="textRojo">FERNANDO CORTEZ RODRÍGUEZ</small> al <strong class="textVerde">SCE 2018</strong></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center maxWidthHeigth" style="height: 30%">
   <h4 class="maxWidthHeigth">Has ingresado con el usuario <strong>FERCOR</strong></h4>
  </div>
 </header>
 <nav id='navTablero' class="nav navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand bg-dark justify-content-end" style="height: 5%;">
  <a href="../../../control/login/logout.php" class="navbar-brand">
   <span style="margin:0"><i class="fas fa-sign-out"></i> Salir</span>
  </a>
 </nav>
 <section id='tableroAdmin' class="container-fluid tablero maxWidthHeigth">
  <div class="row fullWidth">
   <aside  class="col-2 fullWidth asideTablero maxWidthHeigth">
    
   </aside>   
  </div>
 </section>
 <footer class="card-footer container-fluid footer maxWidthHeigth">
  <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
   <p class="text-white"><strong>2018</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <small></small>
  </div>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: de no ser estrictamente necesario ya que replique tu ejercicio yo le quitaría las propiedades que metiste dentro de las etiquetas html y body solo dejando a body asi mira   body{
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

Comment: @ShadowPaz he quitado el html, pero me desaparece el aside, ¿a que se debe eso?, si se hace responsive pero solo causa ese problema.